# Django ORM relations one-to-many

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    body = models.TextField()
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I'd like to add a functionality of *upvoters* to know on what products user has already voted. **I need this to allow users vote on the one product only once.**
Again, to clarify - user can vote on several products but only once on each.
So the relation is *one product - many users (upvoters)*.
I tried to add the next field but cannot make a migration even if default field is provided. Also I tried to clear the database but again cannot make it work.

```
upvoters = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='upvoted')
```

I suppose it works the next way:

> Field to determine upvoted products.
>   To check if user has been upvoted on product, call: `User.upvoted.filter(id=product.id).count() == 1`
>   This means that user has already upvoted on this product.

What's wrong? What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Which side is the *one* in this relationship? Can a product only be upvoted by one user? Can a user only upvote one product? Sounds more like a many-to-many to me ...

Comment: @shmee thanks for your clarification. I've edited the question

Comment: According to me, ManyToManyField will  be a good option because then you can add the user who upvoted into and who doesn't and to count then, that will be also easy or for count you can make another column which will store the count of upvote and whenever a user does reverse of upvote you can simply subtract one from the total

Comment: Unless I really miss something, it seems your understanding of DB relationships is wrong. Despite your edit, it still sounds like any user should be able to upvote any product. That means a product must relate to many users and a user must relate to many products. That's [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). How _many_ individual relations between any specific product and any specific user you allow is an implementation detail. Have a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use ManyToMany, but you can use a custom through model to restrict the product/vote combinations.

To Product class, add:

```
voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ProductVote', related_name='product_voters')
```

Then add the custom through model:

```
class ProductVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Vote, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'product']
```

If you try to add a vote for the same user/product combination, an IntegrityError will be raised.